# How to fix Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference' not found?

Tags: php, google-api

I get Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference' not found when I trying upload file to google drive. How can I fix it? I think the Api miss the class '**Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference**' in **Drive.php**

```
insertFile($service, $title, $description, $parentId, $mimeType, $filename) {
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName($title);
$file->setDescription($description);
$file->setMimeType($mimeType);

// Set the parent folder.
if ($parentId != null) {
    $parent = new Google_Service_Drive_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId($parentId);
    $file->setParents(array($parent));
}

try {
    $data = file_get_contents($filename);

    $createdFile = $service->files->create($file, array(
        'data' => $data,
        'mimeType' => $mimeType,
    ));

    // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID
    // print 'File ID: %s' % $createdFile->getId();

    return $createdFile;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

}

Comment: Apparently Google executed a breaking change from `v1.1.7` to `v1.1.8` and removed previously-required classes. We had to revert to 1.1.7. Bad Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The api certainly simplified the entire process. Add field 'parents' during folder creation

```
        $folder = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array(
                'name' => 'sub-folder-name',
                'mimeType' => 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
                'parents' => array('parent-id')
        );
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call the class again just do it like this

```
$file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$file->setName($filename);
$file->setDescription($description);
$file->setParents(array($parentId));
```